# ChangeEmailAsync "invalid token" in asp.net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I encountered this issue while developing an app and didn't find any question related to it.

I'm using asp.net Core 3.1, win 10.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in "ConfirmEmailChange.cshtml.cs":

```
// code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code)); // DELETE THIS LINE
var result = await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, email, code);
```

That fixes the problem.